# Understanding f /@ g[x,y,z]

Tags: head

According to the Mathematica guide,

```
In[26]:= f /@ g[x, y, z]

Out[26]= g[f[x], f[y], f[z]]
```

In a simple example, this works as desired with symbolic values:

```
In[139]:= f[a_] := a^2; g[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z ; 
          f /@ g[x, y, z]

Out[140]= x^2 + y^2 + z^2
```

However this does not work with integer entries:

```
In[141]:= f /@ g[1, 2, 3]

Out[141]= 6
```

Why does `f /@ g[1, 2, 3]` return 6 instead of 14?

Comment: To see what is going on you may use "Trace":  f /@ g[1, 2, 3] // Trace and you then note that g is evaluated before f

Comment: @DanielHuber I see, but why is f evaluated before g when it is applied to symbolic values x,y,z? I don't get why the evaluation is different.

Comment: Actually f /@ (x + y) returns x^2 + y^2; but  f /@ (2+3) returns 5 ! That is, f is not even evaluated... .

Comment: `f /@ g` similar to  `Pullback` in mathematics :-)  `Plus[2+3]` and `Plus[x+y]` are  difference since `Plus[x+y]` need to defer calculate, I think.

Comment: @Minkowski `g[1,2,3]` it is not a function, it is numerical expression. Try, for instance `f /@ g[x, y, 3]`

Comment: Okay, I see what is the reason. So what would the correct sintaxis be if I want to get  `g[f[1], f[2]],f[3]]  = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^3 = 14` ?

Comment: One way `f /@ Unevaluated[g[1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: Compare: f /@ g[x, y, z] // Trace and f /@ g[1, 2, 3] // Trace. You see that in both cases g gets evaluated (MMA evaluates arguments before functions). However the expression Plus[x,y,z] can not be evaluated further, but Plus[1,2,3] can. In the former case f maps onto Plus[x,y,z], in the latter onto 6 what is an atom.

Answer (score 2):

The correct input for the intention is:

```
f /@ Unevaluated[g[Unevaluated[1], Unevaluated@2, Unevaluated@3]]
```

(* 14 *)

for numbers according to [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html)

Comment: Or `(f /@ Inactive[g][1, 2, 3]) // Activate`

Comment: Okay, but is there a more intuitive explanation of what went wrong here? For those of us that don't want to guess random combinations of evaluate or unevaluate when our code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Given the explanation of the problem in the comments above, explicitly mapping f on the list is likely the cleanest approach in this case.

```
g @@ f /@ {1,2,3}
```